# iOS Shortcuts App: How can I convert my Workflow to a service app?

Tags: ios, shortcut, automation

Back in AppleScript or Apple Automator it is possible to convert workflows to a compiled read-only application.

Is it possible to hide, compile or convert my iOS Shortcuts workflow to a self-running service, too? So far I don't see any way to lock or prevent changes to my workflow.

Comment: I think this is a no (especially on iOS 12 and lower). Have you experimented with sharing a Shortcut iCloud link and then seeing if that link can be archived - recorded so you can go back to it if you delete the original or modify the original?

Comment: @bmike: I don't want to share or archive the workfow. Instead I would like to prevent any changes.

Comment: Not possible, so the best you can do is wipe it and reload t from code control outside iOS if you think it changed.

Comment: Are you looking at iOS 14 developments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn’t possible. You would need to compile an app to import and run these “locked” scripts.

Xcode lets you install your own apps without needing a paid developer account.

Comment: Thanks, I was expecting this kind of answer. I will take look into Xcode